# Task is in None state. So can not see logs

Tags: python, airflow

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_hello():
 print('Hello Wolrd')

dag = DAG('hello_world',
description='Hello world example',
schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
start_date=datetime(2021, 3, 14),
catchup=False)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

hello_operator
```

When I run it using Trigger DAG and check the logs in the graph view the `Log by attempts` is missing. The `Task Instance Details` says

| Dependency | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| Task Instance State | Task is in the 'None' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run. |
| Dag Not Paused | Task's DAG 'hello_world' is paused. |

Answer (score 1):

Your DAG seems to be paused. DAGs are paused by default.
There is a toggle to the left from the DAG id on UI home page.